Simplify $\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor}{5}\rfloor$
Recently when learning SICP, I reread exercises done before (about 20)
after schemewiki is resumed with some updates. I read this code which is the reference of sicp-solutions which is the reference of schemewiki.
It has one equation in this code part:
$$
f(k,3)=\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor^2+\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor+1,k>0
$$
I thought this equation can be easily derived using Arithmetic Progression (See the figure with green nodes in the above sicp-solutions for how this equation is derived):
$$
\begin{align*}
  f(k,3)&=\frac{[f(k,2)+f(k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor,2)]\cdot(\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor+1)}{2}\\
  &=\frac{[(\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor+1)+(\lfloor \frac{k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor}{5}\rfloor+1)]\cdot(\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor+1)}{2},k>0
\end{align*}
$$
I have used codes to check the above 2nd equation. It should be equal to the 1st equation.
The difficult part is $\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor}{5}\rfloor$. I don't know how to simplify such a deep nested floor equation.

Following peterwhy's hints. We let $k=10m+t$ and $q=\lfloor \frac{k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor}{5}\rfloor$
Then we need to prove
$$
\begin{align*}
&&2(\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor^2+\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor+1)&=2+q+\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor+(2+q)\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor\\
\Rightarrow&&\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor-2\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor^2+\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor&=q+(2+q)\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor
\end{align*}
$$

$k\bmod 10<5\Rightarrow q=0$. Then we need to prove
$$
  \begin{align*}
    m\cdot 2m-2m^2+2m=2m
  \end{align*}
  $$
This trivially holds.
$k\bmod 10>=5\Rightarrow q=1$. Similar to the above
$$
  \begin{align*}
    m\cdot (2m+1)-2m^2+2m+1&=1+(2+1)m
  \end{align*}
  $$
This trivially holds again.


If mod is available to your code, and depending on the convention especially for negative $k$, $$k - 10\left\lfloor\frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor = k\bmod 10$$. Dividing this remainder by $5$ and then flooring suggest two cases: $k\bmod 10 < 5$ and $k\bmod 10\ge 5$.

@peterwhy Thanks. Here we only consider $k>0$. I will update the question by following your hints.

@peterwhy Your hints are clear and the question has updated with the answer following your hints. Do you know how to directly get the equation used by the code author?

Minor thought: the 1st equation can be factorised into
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor^2+ 1
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor-1\right)\
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left( \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right)
\end{align*}$$

@peterwhy Thanks for your inspiration. I get it. Then we need to derive $\lfloor \frac{k-10\cdot\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor}{5}\rfloor=\lfloor \frac{k}{5}-2\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor\rfloor=\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\rfloor-2\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\rfloor$ where the last equality is got from $\lfloor a-k\rfloor=\lfloor a\rfloor-k,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Good, I was also on my way of writing an answer using this factorisation.

The 1st equation can be factorised into
$$\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor+1
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor^2+ 1\\
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor-1\right)\\
&= \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right) \left( \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor+1\right)
\end{align*}$$
To match the 2nd equation means
$$\begin{align*}&&
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor &= \frac12\left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{k - 10\left\lfloor\frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor}5\right\rfloor\right)\\
&\iff & \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor \frac{k - 10\left\lfloor\frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor}5\right\rfloor\\
&&&= \left\lfloor \frac k5 - 2\left\lfloor\frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor
\end{align*}$$
The last line is true because $2\left\lfloor\frac{k}{10}\right\rfloor$ is an integer.
